# Handling multiple Promises in Cypress command

Tags: javascript, cypress

#### What I have

I have command that can request token and it resolves promise on response. Once the promise is being resolved - I put the token into the sessionStorage in SomeTest.js. **It works.** But I have to put exactly same `cy.window()...` in every test.

SomeTest.js:

```js
before(()=>{
  cy.login().then(res=>
    cy.window().then((window) => {
       window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', JJSON.stringify(res))
    })
  );
});
```

command in commands.js

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', function () { 
    fetcher.emit('tokenRequest',{email:'dummy@mail.com', password:'dummy'});
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetcher.on('onTokenResponse',function(response) {
            resolve(response);
        });
    });
});
```

---

#### What I want

I would like to set sessionStorage in command `login()` too.

SomeTest.js:

```js
before(()=>{
  cy.login();
});
```

command in commands.js

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', function () { 
    fetcher.emit('tokenRequest',{email:'dummy@mail.com', password:'dummy'});
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetcher.on('onTokenResponse',function(response) {
            cy.window().then((window) => {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response));
                resolve(response);
            })
        });
    });
});
```

**But it throws error**: `Uncaught CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.`, `The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:> cy.window()`.

---

I understand the problem is that I am trying to call another promise which is not being returned. But how can I achieve something like this?

I need to

1. emit `tokenRequest`
2. wait for the `tokenResponse`
3. get `cy.window()` and set some sessionStorage item

---

#### Edit:

I've found walkaround and I've wrapped login into another function/command which seems to be working but I am not sure how pretty is this solution.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('loginFull', function () {
    return cy.login().then((response)=>{
        cy.window().then((window) => {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that works is to move the `cy.window()` command to the outermost level of the custom command, so you are not trying to use it within the Promise.

**Test**

```js
describe('web socket event handler', () => {

  let fetcher;
  before(() => {
    const io = require('socket.io-client'); 
    fetcher = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');
    cy.window().then(win => {
      win.sessionStorage.clear();  // ensure clean before test
    })
  })

  Cypress.Commands.add('login', function () { 
    cy.window().then(win => {
      fetcher.emit('tokenRequest',{email:'dummy@mail.com', password:'dummy'});
      return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetcher.on('onTokenResponse',function(response) {
          win.sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response));
          return resolve(response);
        });
      });
    });
  });

  it('waits for token', () => {
    cy.login().then(_ => {
      cy.window().then(win => {
        console.log(win.sessionStorage.getItem('token'))
        // logs "Response: dummy@mail.com"
      })
    })
  })
})
```

**Server**

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('tokenRequest', function(msg){
    setTimeout(() => {
      io.emit('onTokenResponse', `Response: ${msg.email}`);
    }, 2000)
  });
});
```

---

Ideally would want to make the login command wait on the fetcher event (with timeout?).

I tried this approach [Spying on the DOM API](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/02/05/when-can-the-test-start/#spying-on-the-dom-api), but no luck so far.

---

Another way is to set a flag within the event listener, and add a command to the queue that waits on it.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', function () { 
  cy.window().then(win => {
    fetcher.emit('tokenRequest',{email:'dummy@mail.com', password:'dummy'});
    let flag = { done: false };
    fetcher.on('onTokenResponse',function(response) {
      win.sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response));
      flag.done = true;
    })
    cy.wrap(flag).its('done').should('equal', true); // wait here until done
  });
});
```

Now you can call login synchronously

```js
it('waits for token', () => {
  cy.login();
  cy.window().then(win => {
    console.log(win.sessionStorage.getItem('token'))
    // logs "Response: dummy@mail.com"
  })
})
```

Comment: Pretty well described solutions. I am currently using different solution (mentioned below "Edit" in my question) but both of your solutions works well!

Answer (score 1):

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', function () { 
    function waitForSocket(callback) {
        fetcher.emit('tokenRequest',{email:'dummy@mail.com', password:'dummy'});
        fetcher.on('onTokenResponse',function(response) {
            callback(response);
        });
    }

    waitForSocket((res) => {
        cy.window().then((window) => {
           window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', JJSON.stringify(res))
        })
    })
});
```

The error points to this: [Cypress commands are already promises and they will wait/resolve themselves](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages.html#Cypress-detected-that-you-returned-a-promise-from-a-command-while-also-invoking-one-or-more-cy-commands-in-that-promise). So I think there should not be a wrapping promise for the fetcher.
Edit: I think you can wrap the socket tasks in a callback function.

Comment: It's still same. It ends on `The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:> cy.window()`

Comment: The problem is that `fetcher.on(method,callback)` is not using Promise but It uses callback as second parametr. But what's weird that Cypress throws again error with `Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise. The cy command you invoked inside the promise was: > cy.window()`

Comment: May I ask where does fetcher come from? I would like to recreate this scenario

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It's socket io client. `const io = require('socket.io-client');
const fetcher = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');`. As far as I get is to put another function before it (see **edit** in my post if it helps)

Comment: I think I got it, you can wrap the socket tasks in a callback function, I edited the answer